# How to read csv file where columns are separated by double quotes and spaces

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried googling and searching stackoverflow already, but most similar answers involve some other character acting as a separator (like comma or |) but in the csv I have, a line of data looks like this:

"2017-02-27 ""2017-02-25"" ""15438"" ""2017-02-27",19,"671"" ""1"" ""14"" ""John Smith"" ""614""

And each value is meant to be a column (so above would be 8 columns). Another problem is the value *2017-02-27",19,"671* is all in one column, which includes single quote marks and commas.

So it seems like the delimiter is this: "" ""

How can I read this in properly?

Also, as a side question, the headers are also listed as the first row of the csv file, but they are separated with just spaces (with the headers themselves using underscores such as: name_1 name_2 name_3). Is there a way to read this in while using read_csv or easier to just copy that row and paste it in to the *name* parameter as a list?

Thanks!

Edit: I already tried sep='"" ""' which returns everything as one column. Here is everything I tried (taken from other stackoverflow threads):

```
sep='"" ""'
sep=',\s+',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
sep=" ", quotechar="~"
sep='["]* ["]*', engine='python'
```

Edit:

I found a solution that worked for my specific case:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, sep='\s""', engine='python', skiprows=1, index_col=False).replace('"','', regex=True)
```

in case it helps anyone. Basically, I just separated by 2 double quotes since that separated the first two columns (as opposed to 4 double quotes for the rest) and then used the replace bit through RegEx. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: that is some messed-up delimiting.  I would say that your delimiters (plural) are: Either single-quote OR a comma, and that you've also got a bunch of empty fields in that row.

Comment: tell me about it! I have no idea why they did this, I'm just the guy who has to deal with it now lol since I'm only an intern

Comment: This is a good question but please post the code you have already tried!

Comment: Just updated to include the things I tried, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I take your data as you have it and place in a csv file, and run this

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, sep='\s', engine='python').replace('"','', regex=True)
df
```

I get

```
            0           1      2                  3  4   5     6      7    8
0  2017-02-27  2017-02-25  15438  2017-02-27,19,671  1  14  John  Smith  614
```

Then split the column in question:

```
df[['n1', 'n2', 'n3']] = df.loc[:, 3].str.split(',', expand=True)

            0           1      2                  3  4   5     6      7    8          n1  n2   n3
0  2017-02-27  2017-02-25  15438  2017-02-27,19,671  1  14  John  Smith  614  2017-02-27  19  671
```

If this isn't the result your looking for, please comment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you had and ran into this error: ParserError: Expected 30 fields in line 6, saw 31. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.


I also ran `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delim_whitespace=True) and got this error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 28 fields in line 59, saw 29.


Any idea what's going on? I checked both these lines in a text editor and there's nothing wrong with them and nothing different from any other row in the csv, so I have no idea. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear. If you know which line it is, you can post more data, but really it sounds like the single line you've posted may not be representative of how all data rows are setup.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I cannot paste the full line here as I signed an NDA. But rereading the line, there are not missing quotations marks or spaces or anything like that. Any idea what these errors generally mean? What does it mean by expected 28 fields but saw 29? Thanks!

Comment: try some variations on the separator. it means a double space is being parsed into larger number of fiels. so try sep=' \s' and sep=' \s+'  and sep='\s+' if none work you can take your data and change the values to protect your NDA

Comment: I figured out what it was, there is a name on that line that is three words whereas most names are 2 words. The names column is separated by spaces as well. How can I let it know that these names are actually one column, but the other spaces delimiters?

Comment: Other than skipping the line in import, I’m not sure. You may want to look at processing the file before creating the data frame. Or have someone rebuild the file. Good luck!